# Static assignment of object instead of dynamic reference

Tags: arrays, vb.net, object

I want to make a static assignment of an object to an aray of those objects.  At the end of the code below, all three entries (0,1,2) in the CO_m_contractInfo array point to m_contractInfo which contains info from 3rd contract. The desire is for the array to contain static info for the 1st, 2nd and 3rd contracts.

How can I achieve static assignments so the array contains contract info for all 3 contracts?

```
Private m_contractInfo As IBApi.Contract

Public CO_m_contractInfo() As Contract

ReDim CO_PO_m_contractInfo(0 To 10)

' info from 1st contract loaded into m_contractInfo

CO_m_contractInfo(0) = m_contractInfo

' info from 2nd contract loaded into m_contractInfo

CO_m_contractInfo(1) = m_contractInfo

' info from 3rd contract loaded into m_contractInfo

CO_m_contractInfo(2) = m_contractInfo

' at this point, all three entries (0,1,2) in the CO_m_contractInfo 
' array point to m_contractInfo which contains info from 3rd contract
```

Answer (score 1):

If your question is that the array contains three pointers to the same object and it shouldn't then the answer is that you have to new the m_contractInfo variable each time you add it to the array so that it is a different instance each time.

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort reviewing and answering.What I think I want is a static copy of the contents of m_contractInfo in each member of the array with (0) holding a static copy of the 1st contract, (1) holding a static copy of the 2nd contract, and (2) holding a copy of the 3rd contract.  If the CO_m_contractInfo array is Redim'd each time ... won't the pointers previously loaded into CO_m_contractInfo just be invalid ?

Comment: I see. Redim'ing wont invalidate elements already in an array but that is not your problem. I think what your looking for is a snapshot of the object at each contract stage. 1,2 and 3. because you are storing a reference pointer obviously any changes to the object will affect all pointers to it. The only way to avoid this is to make a copy of the object at each phase and store that in each element. This article might be useful. https://www.infoworld.com/article/3109870/my-two-cents-on-deep-copy-vs-shallow-copy-in-net.html

Comment: Appreciate the information and reference.  Still having trouble finding an example that mirrors my challenge, which is to copy a single instance of the object into an array of object instances.  In the example, the "cloning" is accomplished in a Dim statement ... whereas in my case the array that I want to copy/clone into has already been Redim'd.